# I want to Connect My Java Desktop Application with an Android Application to send and receive data from it. NOTE : USB Debugging

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Connect my Java Desktop Application with my Android app using USB debugging and I want to send and receive data from both the ends.
Kindly help....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.